# Optimal 2D FFT sizes on NVIDIA GPUs

Tags: gpu, fft, cupy

We are benchmarking 2D FFT performance on an NVIDIA A100 in order to determine which sizes have the best performance. The following shows how the runtime for each size is performed. GPU memroy is cleared after each size is run.

```
def run_fft():
    fft2(array, axes=(-2, -1), overwrite_x=True)
timing = cupyx.timing.repeat(run_fft, repeat=10, n_warmup=1)
```

Running it across a range of possible sizes results in the measurements below [image: 2D FFT benchmark].

As you can see, there seems to be a set of sizes that are slower than the rest (the quasi-linear streaks above the main sequence). These sizes also include ones which are factors of low prime numbers (such as 2 and 3). I was wondering whether there is a general rule to define which 2D FFT sizes run optimally (for example, for the CPU case and when using fftw3, the general rule is defined [here](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html):.

Comment: We can't see from the figure what the exact sizes are, but the classical easy ones are 2^N - i.e. 512, 1024, 2048 and 4096 in your range.  Generally, there are 2 cases to consider for FFT's. Either you can choose, in which case you use one of those, or you can't choose, in which case the performance is a given.

Comment: FFT sizes that are multiples of 32 are all good performing sizes, given a warp size of 32. I understand it's a take-it-or-leave-it situation, it's more of a curiosity about what results in the behaviour shown.

You can also pad FFTs, so if you have an FFT size which is "slow" then you can select the next "fast" size, which is what we want to do, and it is ideal to select the next best one rather than jump to a much higher size (say, the next power of 2) if you have a large number of FFTs to perform.